# `hosts.allow` updated by PHP not working

Tags: php, ftp, vsftpd, hosts.allow

Good afternoon, I am working in giving logged in user controlled FTP access.
Reason: I don't want FTP access open to all IP addresses on the internet.

What I am trying to achieve is when a user logs in at the website a PHP script adds their IP address to the `hosts.allow` list.

What I am currently experiencing: PHP is adding the address, but I can't connect to the FTP server. When I make a little change on my own through `nano` it directly works.

My question is am I doing something dumb or do I miss something?

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
$myfile = fopen("/etc/hosts.allow", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$current = fread($myfile,filesize("/etc/hosts.allow"));
echo $current . "<br>";
echo "test";
$myfile = fopen("/tmp/hosts.allowprepare", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$newline = $current . " " . $ip;
fwrite($myfile, $newline);
fclose($myfile);

echo copy("/tmp/hosts.allowprepare","/etc/hosts.allow");

?>
```

Comment: i think that without an helper you will not write to any outsite of yozr pub directory, which chmod does your allow hosts have?

Comment: I changed that to 666, so it could be written by PHP.

Comment: what happening wgen running it from console?